# HTML/JavaScript Quiz not Working on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, safari

So I made a quiz with HTML/JavaScript/CSS and it works perfectly but when I try it on my iPad my results always show up as 0/10. This is my code:

```css
p1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p12, p14, p16, p18, p20 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p13, p15, p17, p19, p21 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  /* Gradient Background Image */
  editor/#d0e4f7+0,73b1e7+24,0a77d5+50,539fe1+79,87bcea+100;Blue+Pipe+%231 */
  background: rgb(208,228,247); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%, rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%, rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%, rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%, rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d0e4f7', endColorstr='#87bcea',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<p1>Fun Apple / Microsoft Quiz - Test Your Knowledge!</p1>

<br>
<br>

<body>

<script>
function returnScore() {
    alert("Your score is " + getScore() + "/10");
}
 </script>
 <form id = "form1">

     <ul>
     <p2>Question 1. In what year was Microsoft founded?</p2>
     <br>
     <p7> <input type = "radio" name = "question0" value = "A" > 1975 <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question0" value = "B" > 2002 <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question0" value = "C" > 1983 <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question0" value = "D" > 1997 <br> </p7>
     </ul>

     <br>

     <ul>
     <p3>Question 2. Who were the founder(s) of Microsoft?</p3>
     <br>
     <p8> <input type = "radio" name = "question1" value = "A" > Bill Gates and Paul Allen <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question1" value = "B" > Michelle Obama <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question1" value = "C" > Steve Jobs and Ronald Wayne <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question1" value = "D" > Steve Wozniak <br> </p8>
     </ul>

     <br>

     <ul>
     <p4>Question 3. When did Steve Jobs pass away?</p4>
     <br>
     <p9> <input type = "radio" name = "question2" value = "A" > September 10, 2013 <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question2" value = "B" > June 14, 2007 <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question2" value = "C" > October 5, 2011 <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question2" value = "D" > January 2, 2001 <br> </p9>
     </ul>

     <br>

     <ul>
     <p5>Question 4. When was Apple founded?</p5>
     <br>
     <p10> <input type = "radio" name = "question3" value = "A" > September 15, 2004 <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question3" value = "B" > November 19, 1954 <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question3" value = "C" > April 1, 1976 <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question3" value = "D" > August 4, 1999 <br> </p10>
     </ul>

     <br>

     <ul>
     <p6>Question 5. Who developed smartphones before - Apple or Microsoft?</p6>
     <br>
     <p11> <input type = "radio" name = "question4" value = "A" > Apple <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question4" value = "B" > Microsoft <br> </p11>
     </ul>

     <br>

     <ul>
     <p12>Question 6. Why is the company named "Apple?"</p12>
     <br>
     <p13> <input type = "radio" name = "question5" value = "A" > Steve Jobs liked apples <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question5" value = "B" > Apples are the Lords of Earth <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question5" value = "C" > Because it comes before Atari in the phone book <br> </p13>
     </ul>

     <br>

     <ul>
     <p14>Question 7. True or False: The Microsoft start-up sound was made by Brian Eno.</p14>
     <br>
     <p15> <input type = "radio" name = "question6" value = "A" > False <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question6" value = "B" > True <br> </p15>
     </ul>

     <br>

     <ul>
     <p16>Question 8. True or False: Microsoft was originally intended to be called "Micro-Soft".</p16>
     <br>
     <p17> <input type = "radio" name = "question7" value = "A" > False <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question7" value = "B" > True <br> </p17>
     </ul>

     <br>

     <ul>
     <p18>Question 9. True or False: Bill Gates wanted to name the company Interfance Manager.</p18>
     <br>
     <p19> <input type = "radio" name = "question8" value = "A" > False <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question8" value = "B" > True <br> </p19>
     </ul>

     <br>

     <ul>
     <p20>Question 10. True or False: If Apple was a country, it would be the world's most populated.</p20>
     <br>
     <p21> <input type = "radio" name = "question9" value = "A" > False <br>
     <input type = "radio" name = "question9" value = "B" > True <br> </p21>
     </ul>

     </form>
     <button onclick = "javascript: returnScore()" > View Your Results! </button>

     <script type = "text/javascript">
         var userInput = [];

var answers = []
answers[0] = "A";
answers[1] = "A";
answers[2] = "C";
answers[3] = "C";
answers[4] = "B";
answers[5] = "A";
answers[6] = "B";
answers[7] = "B";
answers[8] = "B";
answers[9] = "A";

function getScore() {
     var score = 0;
     var numQuestions = 10;
     var form = document.getElementById('form1');

     userInput[0] = form1.question0.value;
     userInput[1] = form1.question1.value;
     userInput[2] = form1.question2.value;
     userInput[3] = form1.question3.value;
     userInput[4] = form1.question4.value;
     userInput[5] = form1.question5.value;
     userInput[6] = form1.question6.value;
     userInput[7] = form1.question7.value;
     userInput[8] = form1.question8.value;
     userInput[9] = form1.question9.value;

     for (var i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++) {

          if (userInput[i] == answers[i]) {
               score += 1;
          } else {
               score += 0;
          }

     }
     return score;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly fine on any other device, displaying the results as it should but whenever I press the button on my iPad (I'm using Safari) it says "Your score is 0/10" no matter what. Is this a problem with Safari or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use safari browser to test this.

Comment: Have you checked your console? It appears fine on my iPad running iOS 10.1.1.

Comment: does this happen with just one question?  Please make a smaller quiz (ie minimum viable problem) haha I dont want to answer ten questions to debug this.